# Full width header with different extremities

Tags: html, css

[image: Header image]

Hi all,
I've been trying to make a header for a website I'm working on like the image above, the issue is I would like that the header fill 100% of the page width.
Is it possible to show me a way to do this in HTML5/CSS3 without using this image as a background img.

Comment: WHAT YOU MAKE JUST SHOW

Comment: *I've been trying to make a header for a website* can we see your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salam my friend, the best idea is to use Css3 proprieties i mean the gradient role, i made a demo for you, you can costumize it as u need.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FBpEv

Answer (score 2):

You need to create everything on 100%, fully flexible. Try the code given below [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xCyL3/15/)

This is just to make you understand how you can do this.

**CSS**

```
body { background: #ccc; margin:0; padding: 0;}
header {background: #fff; width:100%; float:left; height:60px; position:relative;}
nav {background: red; height:30px; width:100%; float:left; margin-top: 30px;}
.logo {
    position:absolute;
    width:150px; height:80px;  background: #fff;
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 0; left:0; top:0;
}
.triangleDown { width: 0; height: 0; border-left: 50px solid transparent; border-right: 35px solid transparent; border-top: 81px solid #fff; left: 98px; position: absolute;}
```

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="triangleDown"></div>
    <nav></nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's usefull, by any chance you could have a way not to position the header on the absolute left with a fixed 150px of width ?
I mean whenever I expend the page the content of the header stand in the center of the page while the the sides expand until to the end of the windows width.

Comment: hey, I have updated my fiddle. Reopen the same link, its little hacky but will work in every resolution with your original widths.

Answer (score 1):

set the containing div to 100% and have a bg image of 1px wide and repeat the image. above this will sit the original main image with margin: 0 auto;

This will give you the desired result as above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it has examples of what you want:
http://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
html, body{height:100%; width:100%;}
header{width:100%; background:#ccc;}
```

Comment: Merry Christmas to you too, but that wasn't helpful :p